# XCode Warning: Using 'stringWithString': with a literal is redundant

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, warnings, stringwithstring

I got the following warning

`Using 'stringWithString': with a literal is redundant`

while using the method `usingWithString`

```
[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: content/unknown\r\n\r\n"]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved the issue by replacing `[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: content/unknown\r\n\r\n"]` to `@"Content-Type: content/unknown\r\n\r\n"`

Answer (score 0):

The warning is because of you would better use @"" to init a string.For example:

```
 NSString *s1 = @"s1";
 NSString *s3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"s1"];
```

we can print their address:

```
2017-02-08 11:38:46.997201 Test[7484:2245410] s1:0x10009c088 s1
2017-02-08 11:38:46.997290 Test[7484:2245410] s3:0x10009c088 s1
```

we can find that  they point a same address.So apple recommand to use " @"" " reather than "initWithString".